# ggez resize window without distording drawn elements

Tags: rust, ggez

I use ggez and would like to resize the window. The only way I found is

```
graphics::set_drawable_size(&mut ctx, width, height);
```

However, when I use it, the white circle I drawn turns into a white ellipse, and a seemingly grey circle appears below. So is there another way of resizing window, one that doesn't distort what is drawn ?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add the answer, but add a post that contains the answer, and mark it as the answer. This is just because it will otherwise be considered as a question without answer, and may even get deleted after some time of inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
graphics::set_screen_coordinates(ctx,rect)
```

right after declaring changing size with `graphics::set_mode(ctx,windowmode)` turns the ellipse back into a circle. The gray shape vanishes after reducing the window (this is a pretty obscure thing).